# How to resize and lock Firefox browser windows for specific sizes?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, firefox-extensions, window-manager

How would I re-size and lock Firefox browser windows for specific sizes?

For example, my resolution is higher but I want to fix the width to 768px and lock it.

Answer (score 2):

[Firesizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firesizer/) allows you to resize the window to specific dimensions.

> Firesizer provides a menu and status bar to resize the window
>   dimensions to a specific size. Unlike other similar extensions, this
>   one sets the size of the *entire window*, not just the HTML area,
>   which better reflects the environment that end users will be using.

[image]

Comment: I know about it and many more but I'm looking for a option to lock the resizable browser window too

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Sizer for Windows: http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/

From the web site:

> Sizer is a freeware utility that allows you to resize any window to an
>   exact, predefined size. This is extremely useful when designing web
>   pages, as it allows you to see how the page will look when viewed at a
>   smaller size. The utility is also handy when compiling screen-shots
>   for documentation, using Sizer allows you to easily maintain the same
>   window size across screen grabs.

Comment: Thanks. I know many resizer add-ons but I also want to lock the size

Comment: there was a command to input in the URL input box, but I can't recall what it was. There you were able to set the firefox window size in pixels